# Angular2 CSS issue

Tags: angular, firefox

I am getting my feet wet on #angular and my page not working on #firefox (input text field is not showing any text when typed. It holds the value when submit though).

this is my enviroment

```
firefox version54.0 64bit
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 8.0.0
os: linux x64
@angular/animation: 4.0.0-beta.8
@angular/animations: 4.2.6
@angular/common: 4.2.6
@angular/compiler: 4.2.6
@angular/core: 4.2.6
@angular/forms: 4.2.6
@angular/http: 4.2.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.6
@angular/router: 4.2.6
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.6
@angular/language-service: 4.2.6
ubuntu 16.04
```

angular component CSS code

```
input, textarea {
width:90%;
background-color:#52595B !important;
font-size: 12;
border: none !important;
padding:24px;
box-shadow:none !important;
color:#fff !important;
}

input::placeholder, textarea::placeholder {
color:#95989A;
}
```

This is component html

```
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addProduct(form.value)">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Product name" name="title" [(ngModel)]="title">
  <textarea placeholder="Product description.." name="description" [(ngModel)]="description" rows="3"></textarea>
  <button id="btn" type="submit">Add Product</button>
  </form>
```

Chrome created the following computed css while Firefox does not.

```
input:not([type]), input[type="email" i], input[type="number" i], 
input[type="password" i], input[type="tel" i], input[type="url" i], 
input[type="text" i] {
padding: 1px 0px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
background-color: white;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
user-select: text;
cursor: auto;
padding: 1px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: inset;
border-color: initial;
border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
text-rendering: auto;
color: initial;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: start;
margin: 0em;
font: 13.3333px Arial;
}
```

Comment: Could you please create an Plnkr example (You could base it on https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview ), so that the question is a bit more clear?

Comment: Thank you for the help. https://plnkr.co/edit/tGKGLMvI8FLyGXvpef85?p=preview plunker does not seems to work with [()] two way data binding of angular 2, I have to remove the data bindings. It works nicely on plunker.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "foundation-flex" css framework is the problem. After I remove the stylesheet cdn it works nicely.

```
![firefox with foundation-flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd8K8.gif)
![chrome with foundation-flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu5Vm.gif)
![firefox without foundation-flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6JXw.gif)
```